# See if one string contains another string

Tags: php

I use the following code to check if a string is the session username at the moment.

```
if($_SESSION['username'] == $home || $_SESSION['username'] == $away)
```

I am looking to change that to see if the string includes the session username, not specifically IS the username.

Is there a way to do this?
Thankyou

Edit :

Say the string is "Username1 and Username2", I will "Username1" to be found.

I have done the following:

```
if( ( strpos($home, $_SESSION['username']) !== false)  || ( strpos($away, $_SESSION['username']) !== false) )
```

That doesnt appear to have worked though!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way, of many, would be to use the [`strpos()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) function, which the documentation says is the fastest way to just determine if a substring occurs within a string.

```
if (strpos($_SESSION['username'],$home) !== false)
```

The format of strpos is `strpos(*haystack*, *needle*)`.  So, the above would be true if `$_SESSION['username']` is **Username1** and `$home` is **Username1 and Username2**.

If you actually need the substring back (rather than a position), [`strstr()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) is a good way to go.

Comment: Best to add !== FALSE, your example fails if the string is in the beginning.

Comment: Wouldn't this fail if the session username is at position 0

Comment: @Bob, Thanks for the +!  Both function names are linked to the PHP docs.

Comment: @Luke In your updated case, we just need to reverse the parameters of strpos.  I've modified my answer slightly.

Answer (score 1):

This would work

```
$username = 'theusername';

if(strpos($username,$_SESSION['username']) !== false) {
    // contains username    
}
```