# What is the best way to check whether string $a contains string $b

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [See if one string contains another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3372722/see-if-one-string-contains-another-string)

I have a string each word separated by ","

```
$a="apple,pear,peach";

$b='apple';
```

What is the best way to check whether string `$a` contains string `$b`

Answer (score 2):

If `$b` will not contain `,` use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/de/function.strpos.php):

```
if (false !== strpos($a, $b)) {
  // $a contains $b
}
```

otherwise you can use:

```
if (in_array($b, explode(',', $a)) {
  // $a contains $b
}
```

Comment: +1 I was thinking your second option, but couldn't muster the energy to type it all out.

Answer (score 0):

See [strstr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) or [strpos](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Comment: about strstr: If you only want to determine if a particular needle occurs within haystack, use the faster and less memory intensive function strpos() instead.

Comment: @Nin correct thats why there is a link to the man pages so that phpnewbie can decide for themselves, which of the two methods applies best to their situation. I cannot see the context of the code this is being asked in.

Answer (score 0):

```
strpos($a, $b) !== false
```

Only way I know.

Answer (score 0):

if (strpos($a, $b) !==false) {
  $a contains $b
}

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions. 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: strpos is quicker than a regex at this point